# Netbeans Spring cannot find resource file

Tags: java, html, css, spring, netbeans

I found problem with connecting CSS and JS file from resource directory.

Directory structure :

[image]

JSP File:

```
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="mainCss" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Project Name</title>        
    <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
          xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
          xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
          xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"/>
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>    

   <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="messages" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

When I check what is under stylesheet file in console, I found:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/resources/css/style.css".`

**Path is redirecting to application index.**

Have you got any idea how to fix it? What caused the problem?

Comment: /resources should not be in the path when you write the page markup.  You need to package your app in a WAR and put CSS and JavaScript at the context root.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change

```
<spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="mainCss" />
```

with

```
<spring:url value="./resources/css/style.css" var="mainCss" />
```